# Populate a DataBase from an API in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am building a Django project with a postgresql in it. This databasa has to be populated from an API. This database doesn't have to be updated.
As I understood, the tables inside my database have to be created in my Django `models`. But where should I populate it? 
In a script outside Django or inside my app `views`?

Comment: If you are building API you probably want to use DRF  ->  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Comment: I am not building an API, just an application that uses a database.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Would that be a suitable solution?          https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did find a way to populate my DataBase from Django itself. I added a custom `populate_db` command in `managment/command` that runs a scritp that populate my DataBase from an external API.
Then I just have to run  `python3 manage.py populate_db`